# Force Audio into mic

Tags: java, audio, device

I am looking for a way to take audio data and either send it into the default recording device like a stereo mix or create another virtual audio device.I am using Java(eclipse). I have looked into JMF, but i don't understand how i would send audio to a device. Please let me know if there is  a library more suited for this project, and how to implement it.

****I Would like to create an audio source, so that a program that uses a microphone like skype may use it. Example:I press a button on a sound board and it plays to the other callers.

Comment: A mic is an input device. Can you explain what it means to force audio data into one?

Comment: Create *another Java(eclipse)*?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. Please explain what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm does what you want to do - but im afraid it doesnt work under windows 10 because it uses obsolete API - and it seems to be Abandonware ... too sad

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in standard Java, you will have to branch into native code and even worse, operating specific native code. For example, utilizing [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) you can follow [these Windows specific instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370840(v=vs.85).aspx) to find the audio devices on a Windows system.

Following those instructions won't be easy though- first you need to load the `MMDeviceApi.dll` library and write your own JNA implementation of the [structures](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/StructuresAndUnions.md) and [data types](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/Mappings.md) of `MMDeviceApi.h`. That would allow you to access the [MMDevice API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316556(v=vs.85).aspx) on Windows. That API allows you to enumerate all the audio devices on the system using [IMMDeviceEnumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371399(v=vs.85).aspx), including specifically enumerating only audio input devices.

Once you acquired the appropriate audio endpoint, via the [IMMEndpoint interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371414(v=vs.85).aspx), you could follow [these instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316756(v=vs.85).aspx) to generate a buffer populated with your audio data and send that buffer to the device. But following this second set of instructions requires that you load the `Audioses.dll` library and write another JNA interface for this new library.

Once you have done all those steps, essentially replicating [the functionality described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370851(v=vs.85).aspx) in a cross-language fashion, you will have finally implemented your functionality- but for only **ONE** operating system! For each operating system you will be supporting you will need to do this all over again using that operating systems specific functionality.

The ultimate answer to your question is that there is no one single library that allows you to do this from Java. You can do it, it just requires you to workaround the fact Java does not have a good time interacting with system level resources. The easiest way to implement the functionality would be to skip out on Java almost completely and simply write a library in a lower-level language such as C or C++. If you would like to only implement this on Windows you might even be able to get away with using .Net/C#. C# is very similar to Java and it wouldn't be very hard to switch languages. Basically, the best way to do what you want is via a different language! If what you want is to stick with Java that is possible, but please strongly consider alternatives.